# I just installed a 240GB SSD in my 2017 MacBook Air, and it will not connect to the internet over my Wifi.

Tags: wifi, ssd

I used Command-Option-R on power-up. When I power up, all I get is a spinning globe that quickly has a triangle with an exclamation point and the message 'apple.com/support -3403F'. I cannot connect to the internet to start the OSx download process. How can I get to the point of using Migration Assistant on the MBA and my old MacBook?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly it sounds like the system never gets far enough to enter internet recovery mode. A sign that there is likely a hardware issue. There are a lot of possibilities but a few spring to mind.

1. New SSD not seated properly or something got in the connector
2. Bad new ssd
3. System damaged when the replacement was done
4. Incompatible SSD

First I would take the new SSD out, blow the contacts clean with canned air and closely examine the connectors on both ends. Then replace it carefully, making sure everything is seated properly and try again.

I would verify that what you got is what you ordered **and** that it is indeed compatible with your system. Please include the make/model of SSD in your question. We may be able to help make that determination.

Put the old drive back in and verify it works, if so -sigh of relief- you didn't brick your Mac. If your replacement SSD came with an external USB case you could put it in the case and plug it into the Mac and verify it works. If it doesn't, return it. If it does, call the vendor's tech support. Tell them the symptoms and see what they can do. Possibly replace it, maybe with a different model.

Comment: I did verify 4 times it was a compatible SSD. How do I determine if it is good? I did check the seating, but I didn't verify clean socket or contacts. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I agree with this, but shouldnt wifi be a separate issue?

Comment: If you don't have an external case for it you need to call the vendor's tech support.